# PhoneRTC build issues in PhoneGap - Bridging-Header.h issue

Tags: cordova, build, phonertc

I am sure my problem has something to do with the bridging header but I don't know what.  I found a git issue referenced below which stated to make sure the bridging-Header is correct.  I am not sure how to do that.

https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/issues/31

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PCObserver.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Session.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/SessionDescriptionDelegate.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

Here is part of the PhoneGap IOS build log:

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift
    cd /project
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PCObserver.swift /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Session.swift /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Config.swift /project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/SessionDescriptionDelegate.swift -target arm64-apple-ios7.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -I /project/build -F /project/build -g -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/AlwaysAvailable-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/AlwaysAvailable-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/AlwaysAvailable-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/AlwaysAvailable-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/project/build/include -Xcc -I/project/build/usr/local/lib/include -Xcc -I/project/build/UninstalledProducts/include -Xcc -I/project/build -Xcc -I/project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -working-directory/project -emit-module-doc-path /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhoneRTCPlugin~partial.swiftdoc -O -module-name AlwaysAvailable -emit-module-path /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhoneRTCPlugin~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhoneRTCPlugin.dia -emit-dependencies-path /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhoneRTCPlugin.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhoneRTCPlugin.swiftdeps -o /project/build/AlwaysAvailable.build/Release-iphoneos/AlwaysAvailable.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhoneRTCPlugin.o
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:5:24: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVPlugin'
class PhoneRTCPlugin : CDVPlugin {
                       ^~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:4:2: error: only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc
@objc(PhoneRTCPlugin)
~^~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:7:32: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCPeerConnectionFactory'
    var peerConnectionFactory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:10:24: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCVideoCapturer'
    var videoCapturer: RTCVideoCapturer?
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:11:22: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCVideoSource'
    var videoSource: RTCVideoSource?
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:12:25: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCEAGLVideoView'
    var localVideoView: RTCEAGLVideoView?
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:15:26: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCVideoTrack'
    var localVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:16:26: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCAudioTrack'
    var localAudioTrack: RTCAudioTrack?
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:18:28: error: use of undeclared type 'UIWebView'
    override init(webView: UIWebView) {
                           ^~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:18:14: error: initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
    override init(webView: UIWebView) {
    ~~~~~~~~ ^
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:26:39: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func createSessionObject(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:39:24: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func call(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:50:34: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func receiveMessage(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:63:31: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func renegotiate(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:77:30: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func disconnect(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:98:32: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func setVideoView(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:154:33: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func hideVideoView(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:164:33: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func showVideoView(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:175:26: error: use of undeclared type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand'
    func reset( command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:193:63: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCEAGLVideoView'
    func createVideoView(params: VideoLayoutParams? = nil) -> RTCEAGLVideoView {
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:251:42: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCVideoTrack'
    func addRemoteVideoTrack(videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack) {
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:270:45: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCVideoTrack'
    func removeRemoteVideoTrack(videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack) {
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:554:20: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCEAGLVideoView'
    var videoView: RTCEAGLVideoView
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:555:21: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCVideoTrack'
    var videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:92:28: error: use of unresolved identifier 'CDVPluginResult'
        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsDictionary: json as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:92:52: error: use of unresolved identifier 'CDVCommandStatus_OK'
        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsDictionary: json as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:194:19: error: use of undeclared type 'RTCEAGLVideoView'
        var view: RTCEAGLVideoView
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:204:20: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RTCEAGLVideoView'
            view = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: frame)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:206:20: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RTCEAGLVideoView'
            view = RTCEAGLVideoView()
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:212:9: error: value of type 'PhoneRTCPlugin' has no member 'webView'
        self.webView!.opaque = false
        ^~~~ ~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:213:41: error: use of unresolved identifier 'UIColor'
        self.webView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                                        ^~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:241:30: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RTCVideoCapturer'
        self.videoCapturer = RTCVideoCapturer(deviceName: cameraID)
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:244:26: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RTCMediaConstraints'
            constraints: RTCMediaConstraints()
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:266:13: error: value of type 'PhoneRTCPlugin' has no member 'webView'
            self.webView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.localVideoView!)
            ^~~~ ~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:396:54: error: use of unresolved identifier 'UIColor'
            self.localVideoView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                                                     ^~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:402:13: error: value of type 'PhoneRTCPlugin' has no member 'webView'
            self.webView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.localVideoView!)
            ^~~~ ~~~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:420:13: error: use of unresolved identifier 'UIView'
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            ^~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:439:13: error: use of unresolved identifier 'UIView'
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            ^~~~~~
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:458:13: warning: initialization of variable 'error' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
        var error : NSError?;
        ~~~~^~~~~
        _
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:495:13: warning: variable 'interuptionDict' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
        var interuptionDict:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        ~~~ ^
        let
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:496:13: warning: variable 'routeChangeReason' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
        var routeChangeReason: NSInteger = interuptionDict.valueForKey(AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey)!.integerValue
        ~~~ ^
        let
/project/AlwaysAvailable/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.swift:498:13: warning: initialization of variable 'error' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
        var error : NSError?;
        ~~~~^~~~~
        _
```

Comment: I created a public git with my files that I send to PGB. https://github.com/rodneyworkman291/PhoneGapPhoneRTC.git